# Problem loading databases and tables to my application

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am developing an application in C# where i can create and delete databases, create and delete tables, and attach and detach databases.

My problem is when i load the tables of a database to a datatable, my method to get the tables is with "Select * from Information_Schema.Tables", if i do this, and if i try for example to create a database, it gives me an error saying: "Could not obtain exclusive lock on database 'model'. Retry the operation later.".

If i don't execute the command to get the tables of a database, all works fine, but if i do it, then i can't create or delete databases and do other things, because it gives me errors.

If i try to delete one database it says that it's currently in use.

So I need a solution to this...

Comment: "I have an application in C# to manage SQL databases" - So do I, it's called SQL Server Management Studio!

Comment: I am not referring to SQL Server Management Studio! I am developing an application in c# to do the things i said. So i need help in what i said.

Comment: @user595291
: my point was (which you clearly missed) is WHY are you writing something that does what SSMS does?

Comment: I am developing it because is project to college

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds to me like you aren't closing/disposing a connection somewhere.

Comment: I already have checked, and in every place when i open a connection, i use a try...catch, with a finally which closes the connection...